# dataframe groupby date and resample by seconds for daily change price

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like below.

[image]

I need to get the percentage change of current resample(10s)'s last price compared to daily open price(00:00:00) like below.

There are more than one compid.

[image]

I did something like below, but df_price_curr_last gets error.

```
df_t is the data

group = ['compid', df_t['datetime'].date]
df_price_open = df_t.groupby(group)['price'].first().to_frame()
df_price_open

df_price_curr_last = df_t.groupby(group).resample('10S')['price'].last()
df_price_curr_last/df_price_open
```

Below is the error msg.

```
ValueError: Key 2020-11-06 00:00:00 not in level Index([2020-11-06, 2020-11-07], dtype='object')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can grouping by dates and also by [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html) with `10S`, aggregate `last` and then grouping by first and second level (`compid` and `date`) with [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for repeat `first` value, so possible divide both `Series`:

```
grouper = ['compid',  
            df_t['datetime'].dt.date.rename('date'),
            pd.Grouper(freq='10S', key='datetime')]
df_price_curr_last = df_t.groupby(grouper)['price'].last()
print (df_price_curr_last)


df_price_open = df_price_curr_last.groupby(level=[0,1]).transform('first')

a = df_price_curr_last/df_price_open
```